# What is the probability of measure(n) returns value x?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

```
def rand():
  return random.choice([0, 1, 1, 1])

def measure(n):
  c = 0
  for x in range(0, n):
    if(rand() == 1):
      c += 1
  return c
```

I'm trying to find the probability of every possible return from measure(n).

At first I assume that it would be something akin to $\frac{3}{4}^{x+1}$, but that doesn't fit the expected curve of a peak towards the end before it drops off- then I assume something akin to $\frac{3}{4}^{|x-(n+1)|}$ but that doesn't fit either. (+1 to include a return of 0.)

Additionally, I think the expected value of measure(n) is $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}} = 4$, am I close there or way off?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you, edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

measure($n$) just returns the number of times, out of $n$ trials, that $1$ was selected by your rand() function.  Since on each trial the probability of rand() choosing $1$ is $3/4$, measure($n$) simply follows the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) Bin($n, 3/4$).

So the answers to your questions are:

$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{measure}(n) = x) = \binom{n}{x} (3/4)^x (1/4)^{n-x} \quad   \text{and}  \quad \mathbb{E}(\text{measure}(n)) = 3n/4.
$$